# Get name of column with highest value in a row

Tags: openoffice-calc

I need a formula to get the name of the column with the highest value in each openoffice (libreoffice) calc row, ie:

```
  A0   |   A1   |    A2  |   A3
------------------------------------
field1 | field2 | field3 | heighest*
------------------------------------
  10   |   12   |   8    | field2*
------------------------------------
   7   |    5   |   15   | field3*
------------------------------------
etc...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have openoffice installed to check against it, but this seems to work in a google spreadsheet:

```
=Indirect(Address(1, Match(Max(A2:C2),A2:C2, 0)))
```

[google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnbJ2RkBA73AdEd0TXh1eG5fVlN3M1hwZjZDd1JFb1E&usp=sharing)